# Abstract types in modules in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, signature

I have very simple signature and module in OCaml:

```
module type S = sig
  type t 
  val y : t
end;;
```

and

```
module M2 : S = struct
  type t = int
  let x = 1
  let y = x+2
end;;
```

I cannot use construction like

```
M2.y
```

to get `3` unless i specify the module as

```
module M2 : S with type t = int = struct ...
```

Why is it so? There already is statement, that `type t = int`

Comment: I don't know how to answer this without explaining the entire concept of module signatures and abstract types, which you're better off getting from a proper book. I suggest you read this: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/files-modules-and-programs.html#signatures-and-abstract-types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concrete, `int` value for `M2.y` is indeed not available because the following two conditions are met:

1. the type of `y` is **abstract** in the signature `S`
   (there is no `type t = ...` there)
2. the module `M2` is made **opaque** with respect to the signature `S`
   (in other words, it is restricted to the signature `S` *via* the notation `: S`)

As a result, you indeed obtain:

```
let test = M2.y ;;
(* val test : M2.t = <abstr> *)
```

As suggested by the keyword `<abstr>`, this is related to the notion of **abstract type**. This notion is a very strong feature enforced by OCaml's typing rules, which prevents any user of a module having signature `S` to inspect the concrete content of one such abstract type. As a result, this property is very useful to implement so-called [abstract data types (ADT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) in OCaml, by carefully separating the implementation and the signature of the ADT.

If any of the two conditions above is missing, the type won't be abstract anymore and the concrete value of `y` will show up.

More precisely:

1. If the type `t` is made concrete, you obtain:

   ```
    module type S = sig
      type t = int
      val y : t
    end

    module M2 : S = struct
      type t = int
      let x = 1
      let y = x+2
    end

    let test = M2.y ;;
    (* val test : M2.t = 3 *)
   ```

   But in practice this is not very interesting because you lose generality. However, a somewhat more interesting approach consists in adding an "evaluator" or a "pretty-printer" function to the signature, such as the value `int_of_t` below:

   ```
    module type S = sig
      type t
      val y : t
      val int_of_t : t -> int
    end

    module M2 : S = struct
      type t = int
      let x = 1
      let y = x+2
      let int_of_t x = x
    end

    let test = M2.(int_of_t y) ;;
    (* val test : int = 3 *)
   ```
2. Otherwise, if the module `M2` is made transparent, you obtain:

   ```
    module type S = sig
      type t
      val y : t
    end

    module M2 (* :S *) = struct
      type t = int
      let x = 1
      let y = x+2
    end

    let test = M2.y ;;
    (* val test : int = 3 *)
   ```

Finally, it may be helpful to note that beyond that feature of abstract types, OCaml also provides a feature of **private types** that can be viewed as a trade-off between concrete and abstract types used in a modular development. For more details on this notion, see for example [Chap. 8 of Caml ref man](https://ocaml.org/manual/privatetypes.html).